# NSMutableArray to NSArray sort

Tags: objective-c

i'm trying to sort my core data object by date. but i keep getting this error:

```
incompatible pointer types assigning to 'nsmutablearray *' from 'nsarray *'
```

This is the code that i've made. All my other code is based on a nsmutablearray, so its important the output is a nsmutablearray. How can i do this without getting the error above?

```
devices = [devices2 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES]]];
```

Comment: Well it means that `devices` is a mutable array, but `-sortedArray...` returns an immutable instance. You could probably send a `mutableCopy` (if the objects can be copied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use mutableCopy function. So like

```
 devices = [[devices2 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES]]] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` has an alternative to `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`, which sorts the array in place, instead of returning a new immutable array.

You can use:

```
[devices2 sortUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES] ]];
```

Otherwise, as @Ethan stated above, you can create a `mutableCopy` of the resulting array.